# Resizing of a Line in Silverlight Application

Tags: silverlight

I have included a Line control in a Silverlight application as followss.

```
<Canvas x:Name="Adorner">
 <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
       <Line Stroke="Black"  StrokeThickness="0" Height="80" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
       </Line>
   </StackPanel>
 </Border>
</Canvas>
```

This line appears as expected, but does not allow me to resize it.
Can anyone tell me how can enable resize property of the Line?

Thanks&Regards
Padma

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I find that Line and Rectangle are both a pain in the butt to use, and I generally use a Border control instead:

A Border contol with a width of one is a great line that is more consistent in syntax and databinding capabilities with other "typical" controls like StackPanel and Grid...